# Is there a way to automatically cast double argument to Vector?

Tags: c#, mathnet-numerics

I am currently using the Math.NET Numerics library in a .NET project, and I find myself often writing code like the following:

```
public double Foo(Vector<double> x)
{
    ...
}

...

public double Foo(double x)
{
    return Foo(Vector<double>.Build.Dense(1, x));
}
```

The `Vector` class is from the Math.NET library, and the idea here is that a one-element vector is really just a scalar, so it is both convenient and intuitive to be able to call `Foo` with a `double` argument when the input happens to be 1-dimensional. The call `Vector<double>.Build.Dense(1, x)` implements the type conversion from `double` to `Vector<double>`.

Is there any way to automate this conversion? That is, some way to have `double` implicitly cast as `Vector<double>` when calling a function taking a `Vector<double>` argument?

Comment: You could use an extension method - which would not be a `cast`. Implicit or explicit conversion operators can only be declared inside one of the two classes. You have no acces to `double` for obvious reasons. I guess you don't have access to `Vector<T>` either.

Comment: I briefly looked into the source code of this library. The `Vector` class is abstract and there are many implementations for different platforms and use cases. Therefore, expanding it with new functionality is not straight forward.

Comment: One idea I had was to have the affected classes implement an interface that provides a default implementation of `public double Foo(double x)`, while leaving it to the implementing class to implement `public double Foo(Vector<double> x)`, but apparently default implementations are not inherited, so they are only available if one casts the implementing class as the interface class.

Comment: Maybe an abstract parent class could do the job?

Comment: Can you work with your own implementation of `Vector<T>` ? Meaning inheriting from it and using `MyVector<T>` everywhere ? If this is the case, you can use an implicit conversion operator, declared inside `MyVector<T>`

Comment: Would that really work, since I want to automatically convert `double` to `Vector<double>`, not the other way around? If it works, could you show a minimal example?

Comment: It might be possible to add an implicit conversion using F#. F# (actually the CLR) is a lot more lenient when it comes to extending types you don't own than C# is. You would have to have a separate F# assembly in your solution that does just that. [Here's an example](https://github.com/bert2/FParsec.CSharp/blob/master/src/FParsec.CSharp.LambdaConvert/FSharpFunc.fs) where the static method `From()` is added to the type `FSharpFunc`.

Comment: Hmm, that's interesting. Would Roslyn be able to follow that, out of the box?

Comment: I don't see how Roslyn could help in this scenario. Could you elaborate?

Comment: @ummg: Regarding Mad hatters solution: You could create a custom type `MyDoubleVector`, which is just a wrapper around `Vector<double>` (i.e., it only contains a single field/property `Value` containing the actual `Vector<double>`). Then you define implicit conversions from both `double` and `Vector<double>` to `MyDoubleVector`. That way, a method defined as `Foo(MyDoubleVector v)` should be callable with (a) a double, (b) a `Vector<double>` and (c) an actual `MyDoubleVector`. In your method, you'd just use `v.Value` to refer to the underlying `Vector<double>`.

Comment: @Heinzi Indeed, I didn't think to use composition, only inheritance. This would work nicely.

Comment: The wrapper solution is an interesting one, though I think it might be a little annoying having to use `v.Value` and so on. I came up with a different solution, using a superclass that implements the necessary conversions. Would you mind taking a look at [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77090663/18944437) below and tell me what you think?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is to define an **implicit cast operator** as an **extension**, i.e., for two classes which are not under your control.

Unfortunately, at the time of writing (Sept 2023), this is currently not supported by C#. This feature has been requested multiple times and is being discussed at the C# language repository:

- https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/discussions/515

Comment: I see. That is too bad.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a sample of extension method from `double` to `Vector<double>`
This will not answer totally your question, but will get rid of code duplication at least.

```
public static class DoubleExtensions
{
    public static Vector<double> ToVector(this double x)
    {
        return Vector<double>.Build.Dense(1, x);
    }
}
```

Use it this way

```
public void Foo(double d)
{
    var vector = d.ToVector();
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is a bit neater, but I will still have to write the `public double Foo(double x)` method in each class.

Comment: @ummg: True, but if you use the "arrow syntax" for method definitions, your boilerplate code would become very compact: `public double Foo(double d) => Foo(d.ToVector());`

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I'm trying right now. It seems to cover my usecase pretty well, but **please tell me what you think of it**.

First I followed the suggestion in [Mad hatter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10753712/mad-hatter)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77090063/is-there-a-way-to-automatically-cast-double-argument-to-vector/77090231#77090231) and implemented a couple of extension methods:

```
public static class DoubleExtensions
{
    public static Vector<double> ToVector(this double x)
    {
        return Vector<double>.Build.Dense(1, x);
    }

    public static Vector<double>[] ToVectorArray(this double[] x)
    {
        var vectors = new Vector<double>[x.Length];

        for (int i = 0; i < x.Length; i++)
        {
            vectors[i] = x[i].ToVector();
        }

        return vectors;
    }
}
```

Then I wrote an abstract superclass that defines the various function signatures and type conversions:

```
public abstract class Distribution
{
    public abstract double Density(Vector<double> x);

    public double[] Density(Vector<double>[] x)
    {
        var y = new double[x.Length];

        for (int i = 0; i < x.Length; i++)
        {
            y[i] = Density(x[i]);
        }

        return y;
    }

    public double Density(double x) => Density(x.ToVector());

    public double[] Density(double[] x) => Density(x.ToVectorArray());
}
```

This is the code from my actual use case, so I have done away with the `Foo` artifice. Note also that I define a couple of more conversions than stated in the original question. I want `Density` to be callable both with a single vector input and with an array of vector inputs. And for both of these I want to also be able to call with ordinary doubles in the scalar case.

The subclasses will only have to implement the one abstract method:

```
public class SomeParticularDistribution : Distribution
{
    public override double Density(Vector<double> x)
    {
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

It feels a little bit weird having the superclass be an abstract class instead of an interface, but I couldn't find a nice way to do it with an interface since I need to implement a few of the methods in the superclass (that is sort of the whole point).